# What's a nice method to factor gaussian integers?

Tags: algorithm, math, complex-numbers, prime-factoring, number-theory

I already have prime factorization (for integers), but now I want to implement it for gaussian integers but how should I do it? thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what you want to know.  What kind of platform are you using to implement these algorithms?

Comment: what does platform mean?

Comment: I hope the details I've added to my answer will get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This turned out to be a bit verbose, but I hope it fully answers your question...

A [Gaussian integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) is a complex number of the form

**G = a+bi**

where **i<sup>2</sup> = -1**, and **a** and **b** are integers.

The Gaussian integers form a unique factorization domain. Some of them act as units (e.g. **1**, **-1**, **i**, and **-i**), some as primes (e.g. **1 + i**), and the rest composite, that can be decomposed as a product of primes and units that is unique, aside from the order of factors and the presence of a set of units whose product is **1**.

The **norm** of such a number **G** is defined as an integer: **norm(G) = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>** .

It can be shown that the norm is a multiplicative property, that is:

**norm(I*J) = norm(I)*norm(J)**

So if you want to factor a Gaussian integer **G**, you could take advantage of the fact that any Gaussian integer **I**  that divides **G** must satisfy the property that **norm(I)** divides **norm(G)**, and you know how to find the factors of **norm(G)**.

The primes of the Gaussian integers fall into three categories:

**1 +/- i** , with norm **2**,

**a +/- bi**, with prime norm **a<sup>2</sup>+b<sup>2</sup>** congruent to **1 mod 4** ,

**a**, where **a** is a prime congruent to **3 mod 4** , with norm **a<sup>2</sup>**

---

Now to turn this into an algorithm...if you want to factor a Gaussian integer **G**,
you can find its norm **N**, and then factor that into prime integers.  Then
we work our way down this list, peeling off prime factors **p** of **N** that correspond
to prime Gaussian factors **q** of our original number **G**.

There are only three cases to consider, and two of them are trivial.

If **p = 2**, let **q = (1+i)**. (Note that **q = (1-i)** would work equally well, since they only differ by a unit factor.)

If **p = 3 mod 4**, **q = p**.  But the norm of **q** is **p<sup>2</sup>**, so we can strike
another factor of **p** from the list of remaining factors of **norm(G)**.

The **p = 1 mod 4** case is the only one that's a little tricky to deal with.
It's equivalent to the problem of expressing **p** as the **sum of two squares**:
if **p = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>**, then **a+bi** and **a-bi** form a conjugate pair of Gaussian
primes with norm **p**, and one of them will be the factor we're looking for.

But with a little number theory, it turns out not to be too difficult.
Consider the integers mod p.  Suppose we can find an integer **k** such
that **k<sup>2</sup> = -1 mod p**.  Then **k<sup>2</sup>+1 = 0 mod p**, which is equivalent to 
saying that **p** divides **k<sup>2</sup>+1** in the integers (and therefore also the
Gaussian integers).  In the Gaussian integers, **k<sup>2</sup>+1** factors into
**(k+i)(k-i)**.  **p** divides the product, but does not divide either
factor.  Therefore, **p** has a nontrivial GCD with each of the
factors **(k+i)** and **(k-i)**, and that GCD or its conjugate is the
factor we're looking for!

But how do we find such an integer **k**? Let **n** be some integer between
**2** and **p-1** inclusive.  Calculate **n<sup>(p-1)/2</sup> mod p** -- this value will be either
**1** or **-1**.  If **-1**, then **k = n<sup>(p-1)/4</sup>**, otherwise try a different **n**.
Nearly half the possible values of **n** will give us a square root of
**-1 mod p**, so it won't take many guesses to find a value of **k** that
works.

To find the Gaussian primes with norm **p**, just use [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)
(slightly modified to work with Gaussian integers) to compute the GCD 
of **(p, k+i)**.  That gives one trial divisor.  If it evenly divides the 
Gaussian integer we're trying to factor (remainder = 0),  we're done. 
Otherwise, its conjugate is the desired factor.

Euclid's GCD algorithm for Gaussian integers is almost identical to 
that for normal integers.  Each iteration consists of a trial division
with remainder. If we're looking for **gcd(a,b)**,

**q = floor(a/b)**, **remainder = a - q*b**, and if the remainder is nonzero
we return **gcd(b,remainder)**.

In the integers, if we get a fraction as the quotient, we round it toward zero.
In the Gaussian integers, if the real or imaginary parts of the quotient are fractions, they get rounded to the nearest integer.  Besides that, the
algorithms are identical.

So the algorithm for factoring a Gaussian integer **G** looks something like
this:

Calculate **norm(G)**, then factor **norm(G)** into primes **p<sub>1</sub>**, **p<sub>2</sub>** ... **p<sub>n</sub>**.

```
For each remaining factor p:
   if p=2, u = (1 + i).   
      strike p from the list of remaining primes.
   else if p mod 4 = 3, q = p, and strike 2 copies of p from the list of primes.
   else find k such that k^2 = -1 mod p, then u = gcd(p, k+i)
       if G/u has remainder 0, q = u
       else q = conjugate(u)
       strike p from the list of remaining primes.
   Add q to the list of Gaussian factors.
   Replace G with G/q.
endfor
```

At the end of this procedure, **G** is a unit with norm **1**.  But it's not necessarily
**1** -- it could be **-1**, **i**, or **-i**, in which case add **G** to the list of factors,
to make the signs come out right when you multiply all the factors to
see if the product matches the original value of **G**.

---

Here's a worked example: factor **G = 361 - 1767i** over the Gaussian integers.
**norm(G) = 3252610 = 2 * 5 * 17 * 19 * 19 * 53**

Considering **2**, we try **q = (1+i)**, and find **G/q = -703 - 1064i** with remainder **0**.

**G <= G/q = -703 - 1064i**

Considering **5**, we see it is congruent to **1 mod 4**.  We need to find a good **k**.
Trying **n=2**, **n<sup>(p-1)/2</sup> mod p** = **2<sup>2</sup> mod p** = **4**. **4** is congruent to **-1 mod 5**. Success!  **k = 2<sup>1</sup> = 2**. **u = gcd(5, 2+i)** which works out to be **2+i**.
**G/u = -494 - 285i**, with remainder **0**, so we find **q = 2+i**.

**G <= G/q = -494 - 285i**

Considering **17**, it is also congruent to **1 mod 4**, so we need to find another
**k mod 17**.  Trying **n=2**, **2<sup>8</sup> = 1 mod 17**, no good. Try **n=3** instead.
**3<sup>8</sup> = 16 mod 17 = -1 mod 17**. Success! So **k = 3<sup>4</sup> = 13 mod 17**.
**gcd(17, 13+i) = u = 4-i**, **G/u = -99 -96i** with remainder **-2**.  No good,
so try **conjugate(u) = 4+i**. **G/u = -133 - 38i** with remainder 0.  Another factor!

**G <= G/(4+i) = -133 - 38i**

Considering **19**, it is congruent to **3 mod 4**.  So our next factor is **19**, and
we strike the second copy of **19** from the list.

**G <= G/19 = -7 - 2i**

Considering **53**, it is congruent to **1 mod 4**.  Again with the k process...
Trying **n=2, 2<sup>26</sup> = 52 mod 53 = -1 mod 53**. Then **k = 2<sup>13</sup> mod 53 = 30**.
**gcd(53,30+i) = u = -7 - 2i**.  That's identical to **G**, so the final
quotient **G/(-7-2i) = 1**, and there are no factors of **-1**, **i**, or **-i** to worry
about.

We have found factors **(1+i)(2+i)(4+i)(19+0i)(-7-2i)**.  And if you multiply
that out (left as an exercise for the reader...), lo and behold, the
product is **361-1767i**, which is the number we started with.

Ain't number theory sweet?

Comment: that's interesting but how do I make a program that turns an integer into a list of primes (which multiply to make it)? It seems inefficient to list every gaussian prime which has the right norm, and check if you can divide by it.. but maybe that's the only way?

Comment: @muaddib: if G = a+ib = gp1 * gp2 * gp3* ...*gpn then G' = a-ib = gp1' * gp2' * ... * gpn' where gpi is a guassian prime and z' is the conjugate of z. Norm G = GG' = gp1*gp1' * ..., which is a factorization in _integers_. So all you need to do if factorize the norm, pick primes of from 4n+1 and factorize them further using Hermite-Serret algorithm, which is what Jim described I believe.

Comment: Excellent answer. Small correction (I think) regarding the case of when 2 is a factor. If G isn't divisible by 1+i there's something wrong. `1+i = i(1-i)` so a number is divisible by 1+i iff it's divisible by 1-i, and if it's divisible by 2, then it's divisible by both of them, so there's no need to check divisibility there.

Comment: @Davin: Yep, that sounds correct...I've updated my answer accordingly.  thanks!

Comment: @Jim Lewis: awesome answer.  To the OP: -1 for the remark "that's interesting, but how do I write a program".  Seriously ungrateful.

Answer (score 0):

Use floating point for the real and imaginary components if you want full single cell integer accuracy, and define gsub, gmul and a special division gdivr with rounded coefficients, not floored. That's because  the Pollard rho factorization method needs gcd via Euclid's algorithm, whith a slightly modified gmodulo:

```
gmodulo((x,y),(x',y'))=gsub((x,y),gmul((x',y'),gdivr((x,y),(x',y'))))
```

Pollard rho

```
def poly((a,b),(x,y))=gmodulo(gsub(gmul((a,b),(a,b)),(1,0)),(x,y))

input (x,y),(a,b) % (x,y) is the Gaussian number to be factorized
(c,d)<-(a,b)
do 
   (a,b)=poly((a,b),(x,y))
   (c,d)=poly(poly((c,d),(x,y)),(x,y))
   (e,f)=ggcd((x,y),gsub((a,b),(c,d)))
   if (e,f)=(x,y) then return (x,y) % failure, try other (a,b)
until e^2+f^2>1
return (e,f)
```

A normal start value is a=1, b=0.

I have used this method programmed in Forth on my blog http://forthmath.blogspot.se

For safety, use rounded values in all calculations while using floating points for integers.