# Visualizing gaussian primes and gaussian prime factors in Python

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization, number-theory

I want to create two plots, one that has gaussian primes depicted in complex plane and another one that shows the number of (gaussian) prime factors of that complex number. I can calculate both the primality (the first scenario) and the factors (the second one), but can't find the correct format for the visualization.

In the first case I want to merely draw a tick for every prime in a complex plane of given dimensions, like pictured in [this Wolfram Mathworld page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianPrime.html). I have already defined a function with the following signature: `is_gaussian_prime(c : complex) -> bool`. What I'm missing is a suitable data structure for storing the information of the primacy of all the complex numbers from `real_min` to `real_max` and `imag_min` to `imag_max` and a way to visualize that data structure. I have looked into `seaborn.relplot()` as documented [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/relational.html), but cannot quite grasp, what kind of shape I want the data to be in.

The reason I want to use `relplot()` is because that allows drawing different sizes of ticks for different amount of prime factors in the second scenario. Meaning that I want to draw the second plot in such a way that the size of the tickers represent the number of prime factors of that particular gaussian number. To be more precise, in the second plot I want to draw gaussian primes with a distinct color and gaussian composites as black with bigger ticker size for composites that have more factors. For this case I have a function of the following signature already defined: `number_of_gaussian_factors(c : complex) -> int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a list of gaussian primes, and then call `sns.scatterplot` on the real and imaginary parts:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sympy.ntheory.primetest import is_gaussian_prime

N = 200
prime_set = set()
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if is_gaussian_prime(i + j * 1j):
            prime_set.add(i + j * 1j)
            prime_set.add(i - j * 1j)
            prime_set.add(-i + j * 1j)
            prime_set.add(-i - j * 1j)
primes = np.array(list(prime_set))
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=np.real(primes), y=np.imag(primes), color='tomato', s=20)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.scatterplot of gaussian primes]

Calculating the number of prime factors seems [a bit more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269810/whats-a-nice-method-to-factor-gaussian-integers), and a bit less symmetric (e.g. `2=(1+i)(1-i)` and `2i=i(1+i)(1-i)`). You have an array of gaussian integers (e.g. `gaussian_ints`) and accompanying array of number of factors (e.g. `num_factors`), you could call e.g. `sns.scatterplot(x=np.real(primes), y=np.imag(primes), size=num_factors, hue=num_factors)`.

Comment: I implemented the algorithm provided in that very same SO post. Seems like I can get this done with this info. Thanks!